# Changing single chars to upper or lower case depending on user input in Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, char

I have tried to find guidance on this, but I keep getting solutions on an entire string, or a single character. I am in my 4th week of Java, and have hit a roadblock.

I have to ask a user to input three letters ("Enter three letters: abc"). Depending on which case they type, I have to write a program that swaps upper with lower and visa versa. For example, if the user types "aBc", my output will be "AbC".

This is what I have so far. If my code is horrible, I'm sorry. I'm learning as I go.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LowerUpper {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter three letters: ");

        String letters = input.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {      

        char letter1 = letters.charAt(0);
        char letter2 = letters.charAt(1);
        char letter3 = letters.charAt(2); 

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(0)) == true)
            System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(letter1));

        else {
            System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(letter1));
        }
        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(1)) == true)
            System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(letter2));

        else {
             System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(letter2));
        }

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(2)) == true)
            System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(letter3));

        else {
              System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(letter3));
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I typed "abc" for the input, the output was:

A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C

The format of the output is supposed to be `"Result: ABC"`. I can work on that later. I'm just trying to figure out how to get this to execute correctly. My hunch is that I'm definitely going wrong on my if/else statements. I do not know how to print the changed chars all in a row (abc, AbC, ABC, etc). I thought I did it correctly at the beginning with the indexing of the string (0,1,2).

By the way, it's not showing my output correctly this forum. It is supposed to be one letter per line, not "ABCABCABC", if I made sense with that.

Comment: use  `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: That makes sense. Ok then, how would I combine my three chars? System.out.print("Result: " + Character.toLowerCase(letter1, letter2, letter3); ?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue I see is that you've got a loop going over the length of the string but you're not using the loop index i to reference the individual characters. In short, you're trying too hard and overlooking the obvious.

Wouldn't this do the trick?

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
   char letter1 = letters.charAt(0);   
   if (Character.isUpperCase(letter1)) {
       System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(letter1));
   } else {
       System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(letter1));
   }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. That's what I get for copy and pasting a noobs code with no compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning for this is because it's inside of a for loop, which is essentially worthless, because you are never using the integer 'i'.  If you remove the for loop, it should only execute once, thus for outputting "ABC", instead of "A B C A B C A B C".  To print the chars in a row, you can simply append each character to a string, and then output that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my new code. It compiled with no errors and the output was just as it was supposed to be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LowerUpper {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter three letters: ");

        String letters = input.nextLine();



        char letter1 = letters.charAt(0);
        char letter2 = letters.charAt(1);
        char letter3 = letters.charAt(2);

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(0)) == true)
            System.out.print("Result: " + Character.toLowerCase(letter1));

        else {
            System.out.print("Result: " + Character.toUpperCase(letter1));
        }

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(1)) == true)
            System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(letter2));

        else {
             System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(letter2));
        }

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(2)) == true)
            System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(letter3));

        else {
              System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(letter3));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get a redundant printing 'coz you loop the three variables which already contain all characters.

> To solve your problem. just remove the `for loop`. 'coz you already
>   store each character to the three variables.

You code will look like this now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LowerUpper {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter three letters: ");

        String letters = input.nextLine();



        char letter1 = letters.charAt(0);
        char letter2 = letters.charAt(1);
        char letter3 = letters.charAt(2); 

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(0)) == true)
            System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(letter1));

        else {
            System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(letter1));
        }
        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(1)) == true)
            System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(letter2));

        else {
             System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(letter2));
        }

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letters.charAt(2)) == true)
            System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(letter3));

        else {
              System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(letter3));
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you have a loop then do each letter individually. So get rid of the loop. It would look better if you re-wrote it with a loop but only had one if/else statement inside the loop based on i not 0,1&2.

Answer (score -2):

Replace your for loop with:

```
System.out.println(letters.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Yes, I can't change the case of the entire string. I'm swapping individual chars based on user input.